# Laravel 'with' and nested relation

Tags: laravel

I am retrieving some relationship:

```
$requirements = Requirement::with([
            'countryMatch',
            'applier',
            'doc' ])->get();
```

and my model Requirements contains:

```
public function doc()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Doc::class);
}
```

Right now all fine.

Since my Doc model has its own relationship:

```
public function translation($language = null)
{
    if ($language == null) {
        $language = /*App::getLocale()*/'en';
    }
    return $this->hasMany('App\DocTranslation')->where('language', '=', $language);
}
```

I would like to retrieve this relationship direct in the first 'with' statement, something like this:

```
$requirements = Requirement::with([
        'countryMatch',
        'applier',
        'doc->translation()' ])->get();
```

but I receive error:

```
Call to undefined relationship [doc->translation()] on model [App\Requirement].
```

That's because relation translation is in Doc model not in Requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Nested `with()` calls use dot notation, not object notation. Change it to `'doc.translation'` instead. Do note though that I'm not sure if you can eager load relations that contain application logic.

Answer (score 0):

for a nested relationship use dot like announcement.advertiser

`$requirements = Requirement::with([
            'countryMatch',
            'applier',
            'doc',
            'doc.translation'])->get();`